# mozroots command fails with Unsupported hash error

Tags: mono, certificate, ubuntu-12.04

I am using the following set of command on a new install of 12.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get install -qq python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:v-kukol/mono-testing
sudo apt-get update -qq > /dev/null
sudo apt-get install -qq mono-complete mono-gmcs > /dev/null
mozroots --import --sync
```

The `mozroots` command fails, though, with the following error message.

```
Mozilla Roots Importer - version 3.0.12.0
Download and import trusted root certificates from Mozilla's MXR.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.
Downloading from 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1'...

Importing certificates into user store...

Error: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unsupported hash algorithm: 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3
at Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS1.HashNameFromOid (System.String oid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.Cryptography.PKCS1.CreateFromOid (System.String oid) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.get_Hash () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection.IndexOf (Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection.Contains (Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Tools.MozRoots.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Tools.MozRoots.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I did not have this issue when I used Mono 2.10.8.1 (default version for 12.04). However, I need some of the newer features of Mono for my application now.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed recently. The easiest way to get the fix is to update to Mono 3.2.x. An alternative is using an older Mono (e.g. 2.10) to download the certificates.

Comment: I've just updated to 3.2.8 (the version in the latest Ubuntu 14 beta) and it still suffers from missing hashes - although probably not this one (I'm seeing a different missing hash). Rebuilding Mono is a huge a project, but I might add the hashes myself if I get time. One wonders why all of the new hashes weren't added to v3.2 at the same time...

Comment: @winwaed *known* supported hash were added, but some people *might* be using a different OID for them. It be helpful to file bug reports and include the error message (which would provide the OID).

Comment: Yeah - I'm still working the problem at this end. I guess it is frustrating that .NET has no problems (my app does a lot of web fetching with URLs supplied externally)  but Mono has a host of problems in this area...